# In which form Microsoft SQL password should be given when creating a user?

Tags: sql-server-2008, users, password

I am creating a Microsoft SQL server user with the guidance of [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) and giving the system the following commands:

> CREATE LOGIN MyName WITH PASSWORD = 'MyPass';
>   USE My$DatabaseName;
>   CREATE USER MyName FOR LOGIN MyName;
>   GO

I use SQL Studio to look again the password by clicking the name on `Logins` list. There I see too many stars on the password that it could represent my given password.

**My question is** that if I gave the password according to that I wrote (in plain text), did I give it correctly? I have problems to login to the database and I don't know now is the password there ok or not.

*(The link on MSDN does not say anything about encrypting, but I cannot say if the example passwords follow some encrypting rule or not.)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is there correctly. You have run CREATE LOGIN correctly.

The number of stars in the SSMS box is just a mask and is unrelated to your actual password. SSMS doesn't know or try to read your password from the server

Note that SQL Server doesn't store your password so it can't relate to the `****` in SSMS anyway. SQL Server hashes it into the `password_hash` column of [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174355.aspx)

Comment: +1: In my trouble shooting, I can now tick this part out of the list of possible points of failure! Thank you so much!

Comment: You replied so fast you probably can answer [my another issue on the same trouble shooting list](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/minimum-user-rights-for-connecting-ms-sql-database-remotedly).

Comment: seems to me that what you are concerned with is validating the password. To validate I suggest using SQLCMD utility. I typically validate by running SQLCMD with the following query."PRINT CAST(@@SERVERNAME AS NVARCHAR(100))+ ' | ' + CAST(SUSER_SNAME() AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ' | '+ CAST(DB_NAME() AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ' | ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),120)  "