# Minimum user rights for connecting MS Sql database remotedly

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/walzenbach/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008) for getting connected to a Microsoft SQL Server. I connect with ping functionality of Glassfish Server and thus I have to give some user rights to be able to even ping the Database.

My problem is that probably **my user has not rights to take external connections to the database or even more sad, not any permissions**. What kind of user permissions there should be applied before I can connect to my database with my user?

*(I suppose there are needed some GRANTS before accessing the database, because making that on Mysql needed quite many of them. Now the actual problem is I could not apply the same queries here 'cause the SQL scripts are incombatible)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for "CONNECT" rights

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME(grantee_principal_id), * 
FROM sys.server_permissions WHERE type = 'COSQ'
GO
USE MYDB
GO
SELECT USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id), * 
FROM sys.database_permissions WHERE type = 'CO'
```

To fix as needed

```
USE master
GO
GRANT CONNECT SQL TO myLogin
GO
USE MYDB
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO MyUser
GO
```

Comment: I added CONNECT on a graphical tool (I feel more comfortable with it) and I was able to connect the Database. Thanks.

Comment: To be able to connect from another machine I had to give Firewall pass to `sqlservr.exe` file through the firewall as well as port 1433.

Comment: If its a named instance, better to include port 1434 UDP also.